# Grails "MappingException: Unknown entity" in inherited classes

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, single-table-inheritance

I've got a handful of classes (simplified) in grails 2.5.5:

```
class Solution implements Serializable {
    long id
    String name

    static hasOne = [
        entity : SolutionEntity
    ]

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'companion'
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence: 'SOLUTION_SEQ']
        entity cascade: 'delete'
    }

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: true, blank:false, unique: true
        entity nullable: true
    }
}

class SolutionEntity implements Serializable {
    Solution solution

    Long externalEntityId
    private Object externalEntity

    void setExternalEntity(def value){
        externalEntityId = value.id
    }

    static transients = ["externalEntity"]

    static constraints = {
        solution nullable: false, unique: true
        externalEntityId nullable: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'companion'
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence: 'SOLUTION_ENTITY_SEQ']
        tablePerHierarchy true
    }
}

class SolutionPPB extends SolutionEntity implements Serializable {

    PPB getPPB(){
        if(!externalEntity && externalEntityId) {
            externalEntity = PPB.get(externalEntityId)
        }
        externalEntity
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

where the basic idea is that I want to associate each `Solution` with a `SolutionEntity`, which may be of different types (I've shown `PPB` here). This is based on Burt Beckwith's [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770210/319034) because the `PPB` are in different datasources. I'm able to create and modify `Solution` entries as I like, there doesn't seem to be any problem there. However, when I try to create a `SolutionEntity` object like this:

```
def link = SolutionPPB.findOrCreateBySolution(solution)
link.setExternalEntity(entity)
link.save(failOnError: false)
```

I get the exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: myapp.Solution; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: myapp.Solution
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It seems surprising that `Solution` is unknown since I didn't have any trouble making the `Solution` before trying to link it.

Comment: More than a guess, but can you replace entity for something else like solutionEntity?

Comment: I would also change the class name SolutionEntity to something else.

Comment: I've tried 3 variants: one with the text "entity" substituted to something else (this still failed), and another w/o the subclasses (this worked), and I also tried removing the SolutionEntity references from Solution (didn't work). While it would be nice to do inheritance, I think I need to skip it for now.

Comment: where is the PPB class?

Comment: It's in a different DataSource (and I can't put all of these in the same DataSource), but there's nothing fancy about it -- I just want to record associations between a PPB and a Solution.